# Display the same page even after form submission

Tags: html, tornado

in the below simple form submission, i enter a name and it is printing a message ("BY which i mean the form is gone and only message is being displayed ") after submitting the form but i want to show the same message along with the form

```
enter code here
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class Main(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            self.render("auth.html")
    def post(self):
            ab=self.get_body_argument("username","")
            self.write(ab+" printing in a new page")


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", Main),
    ],debug=True,)

if __name__ == "__main__":
application.listen(8054)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And here is the HTML page for your convenience:

```
<html>

<head>
Welcome
</head>
<body>
    <div id="complete">

        <div id="form">
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <input type= "text" name="username" >
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove "/" from form action it will reload the same page

Comment: @Farhan no bro i tried i think it is refreshing again after the form submission and thereby printing only the self.write ("Message") i want it along with the form fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two separate handlers for POST and GET, but only in GET you are actually render the form. Next, using `write` with `render` is not a good idea - it will work but the text will be outside (before or after) HTML, solution - templates variable.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class Main(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("auth.html", message=None)

    def post(self):
        msg = "{} printing in a new page".format(
            self.get_body_argument("username","")
        )
        self.render("auth.html", message=msg)


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", Main),
    ],debug=True,)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8054)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

And auth.py

```
<html>

<head>
Welcome
</head>
<body>
    <div id="complete">

        <div id="form">
            {% if message is not None %}
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
            {% end %}
            <form action="/" method="post">
                <input type= "text" name="username" >
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

More info about tornado templates: http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html.